# Getting form data without POST or GET in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with an MVC 4 project.  I have a problem passing form data from my view to my action in my controller.  The view I've inherited already has a form tag so I can't nest other form tags within it.  I'm not interested in ajax/javascript as it would take too long to get upto speed.

I have a partial view that displays user details for editing.  I have a Model which holds values of the user which I display.  For example:

```
 <input id="txtFirstName" type="text" name="FirstName" value="<%: Model.FirstName %>"/>
```

I can't use POST or GET because of the existing form tag.  So,if it's possible, I want to overwrite my Model instance with my textbox values whether they've changed or not and pass the Model to my action:

```
<%= Model.FirstName = <FirstName value from textbox> %>
 ....
<%: Html.ActionLink("Save", "UserSave", "User", new {Model})%>
```

But I don't know how to get the value for each textbox  etc.  Page.Form.Field?  Request. ?

I'm aware this is an ugly way to do it and not the way MVC should work.  But this is one of those times when time's short and I need a hack to get it done.  So, please don't answer my question with another question like why don't you use Ajax or Razor etc.

thank you

Comment: I think you might be confused about what code runs on the browser vs what runs on the server, and how data is transferred from one to another.

Comment: No, I'm not.  I've been passing form data with different platforms and languages, from using PERL and javascript on the client side on Linux with C/C++ on the server side through to using MVC today.  I'm relatively new to MVC and, in particular, the scope of the Model that's all.  So please don't patronise me.

Comment: Sorry about that.  The way you phrased your question seemed to imply that you believed the data someone types in a text control in the browser can be sent to the server to be accessed by C# code without using an HTTP request.  And it seems like at least one other person agreed with me.  What did you mean by suggesting `Page.Form.Field` could be populated with a value from the browser without a GET or POST?

Comment: I don't know what I was talking about.  It was late and I was grasping at straws :)  Essentially, I need to take some steps back and study MVC in more depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get data from the client browser to the server, you will need to issue some kind of request.  Whether this is via POST or GET, AJAX or not, a request still needs to be issued - there is no quick hack to get around this.

Without more details, it is hard to give you any answer, however, I can think of two possibilities.

1. Create a new Form in your view - you can't nest them, but you can
   have multiple forms.
2. If the field you want to update in the view is
   also in the existing form, you could have some javascript to copy from your
   text box to the existing field before submission.

Comment: Thanks StanK for your more respectful answer.  It seems I am nesting form tags!  My master page (written by someone else) includes a form which passes an id as the action (eg action="700") so any subsequent form will be nested.  Looks like I need to brush up on javascript and Ajax.

Comment: I see.  One relatively simple hack would be to use some javascript to change the "action" attribute of the form to point to the controller action you actually want to call - and then you can just use the inputs like you normally would. It's a bit of a hack, and ideally you'd get the other person to change their master page - they surely don't need to wrap the form tags around your content.